# How to change permalink for categories?

Tags: wordpress

I have some post categorized under projects and have a link to that category from the main menu navigation. I want the link to have a url like this: http://www.example.com/projects. How can I achieve this for in Wordpress?

Note that I already have my permalinks for blog posts set to: `/%category%/%postname%/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already set that as permalinks, then you should be all set then.

I have that setting on one of my site and it works like what you mentioned.

---

Does these types of links work on your setup?

http://www.example.com/category/projects

http://www.example.com/projects

Comment: No I actually get a 404 if I go to that on my site. (I would provide a link but it is only local at the moment). It actually gives me this link: `/category/s1-static-pages/c2-projects/`

Comment: Ok to make matters much simpler, I went to categories and deleted all the categories I had there. Added a new one called projects. The problem now is that it will not let me create a simple slug called `projects`, just `projects-2`.

Comment: That means you still have "projects" category, remember that when you delete posts/categories, they go into "trash" delete it there as well first

Comment: Excellent, that worked beautifuly :). Actually I had a tag called projects. And a whole bunch of other tags. Removed them all. Tried migrating from a Joomla install to a wordpress before. But doing it manually would be much cleaner and more minimalistic, which is really the goal.
What is the difference between tags and categories anyway?

Comment: glad you fixed it
Tags just allows some way to have some additional urls to organize the posts.

Comment: The only difference I see between them is that categories let you have nested items, while tags do not. Anyway thanks for the help :).

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the categories from the trash and download the plugin No Category Base.

Then category pages will have link like this: http://example.com/projects and not http://example.com/category/projects